# Styling SVG with CSS in the containing HTML

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a SVG file containing one simple triangle named. The file is named indicator.svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!--Scalable Vector Graphic-->
<svg version="1.1" 
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"     
     baseProfile="full">
     <polygon points="0,7 7,0 14,7"/>
</svg>
```

and I have a html with built-in CSS that tries to set the color of the SVG polygon:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
.indicator{
    fill:blue;
}
</style>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<img class="indicator" src="images/indicator.svg" />
</body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't change the color of the triangle within the SVG to blue. How can this be fixed? I want to be able to choose the color of the triangle from inside the HTML while the SVG itself is in a separate file.

Comment: Nowadays, you can include and style external files via `<symbol>` and `<use>`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39663457/1494454).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It is quite obvious why this doesn't work for you. The `fill` CSS property only applies to SVG elements, but you're trying to apply it to HTML `<img>` element. The desired result can be reached other ways:

- Use *true* XHTML (with `application/xml` or `*/*+xml` MIME type) in your main document; then, you'll be able to mix namespaces and append SVG into it. The browsers' support for this solution is pretty good; it will work in every browser supporting XHTML and SVG.
- Some newer browsers (IE9+, Firefox 4+, Chrome) allow you to do the same even in HTML documents.
- Link a stylesheet into SVG document: `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css"?>`. I'd personally choose this way. You won't be able to control the properties' values directly from HTML document, but you won't be required to change the SVG file.
- Append the SVG file into HTML document using `<object>` and use scripting: `oObjElem.contentDocument.getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'polygon')[0].style.fill = 'blue';`.