# How do I have an SVG image inherit colors from the HTML document?

Tags: html, css, colors, svg

I have a bunch of SVG images that I want to embed in an HTML page, which is styled with CSS.

I want to be able to have elements in the SVG have their color inherited from the parent HTML element's color attribute.

I tried setting `style="stroke: none; fill: inherit"` but this doesn't work.

Comment: Take a look at SVG parameters: http://www.schepers.cc/w3c/svg/params/ref.html

Comment: Your question isn't clear on *how* you embed the svg fragments. Sounds a bit like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906148/how-to-apply-a-style-to-an-embedded-svg though. Anyway, if your fragments are inline in the html, then styling like in your example should work fine.

Answer (score 211):

HTML uses color whereas SVG uses fill and stroke. You can get fill or stroke to use the value of the color CSS property by using the value `currentColor` e.g. `fill="currentColor"`

Comment: This doesn't work with embedded SVGs, though, does it?

Comment: It does, but it isn't cross-document if that's what you mean.

Comment: Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/color

Comment: 1million upvotes!

Answer (score 96):

You can use `fill="currentColor"`.

```
<a href="#" style="color:red">
<svg fill="currentColor"> ...</svg>
</a>
```

Answer (score 14):

Define the `fill:` of the whole SVG as `currentColor` in the CSS:

```
svg {
  fill: currentColor;
}
```

This makes the whole SVG to inherit the normal CSS `color:` of the surrounding element. Just make sure that all SVG child elements don't have any `fill` defined.

Answer (score 5):

stroke="currentColor" this worked for me