# SVG currentColor not working in GitHub README?

Tags: css, github, svg

I'm trying make an SVG color match the color of the surrounding text in a GitHub readme. (If setting the text to `"fill=black"`, it'll hardly be visible in GitHub's dark mode.)

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13002311/353337), I gather that I can use

```
fill="currentColor"
```

to get the `color` property of the nearest (surrounding) CSS element. I tried that with an SVG that displays a simple circle:

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" baseProfile="full" viewBox="-500 -500 1000 1000">
  <circle r="400" fill="currentColor" />
</svg>
```

The SVG is embedded in the README as

```
<p align="center">
  <img src="https://nschloe.github.io/smoothfit/disk.svg" width="60%">
</p>
```

However, the fill color will always come out as black.

[image]

(From [here](https://github.com/nschloe/smoothfit#disk)).

Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D for the hint. I've added the code of the SVG. I'm not sure how to capture the GitHub aspect of it in a small piece of code though. If have a suggestion, let me know!

Comment: I don't believe this is possible using the `<img>` element, you'd need to use `<svg>`, which I'm not sure is supported in GitHub markdown.

Answer (score 8):

@Alicia's reply is the correct explanation: For `currentColor` to work, the SVG needs to be embedded in the HTML. It doesn't work if it's included as an `img` tag. This

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  Lorem ipsum
  <p style="color:red">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <circle r="100" fill="currentColor" />
  </svg>
  </p>

  dolor sit amet
  <p style="color:red">
    <img src="https://nschloe.github.io/smoothfit/disk.svg" width="100px"/>
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

gives

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Feb 2024 - currentColor does not seem to be supported but you can provide two svgs, one for dark and one for light mode (e.g. replace 'currentColor' in svg source text with 'white' or 'black')

[GitHub Docs - Specifying the theme an image is shown to](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/getting-started-with-writing-and-formatting-on-github/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax#specifying-the-theme-an-image-is-shown-to)

```
<picture>
  <source media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)" srcset="images/mySvg_cc_white.svg">
  <source media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)" srcset="images/mySvg_cc_black.svg">
  <img alt="Shows my svg">
</picture>
```