# Sprite as <canvas> or as Image

Tags: html, canvas, sprite

I'm writing an HTML5 Javascript game that uses the `<canvas>` tag, and and I'm not sure which is better for a sprite: a `<canvas>` tag or an Image(). A friend says `<canvas>`, so that we can play with its colors, make it blink, etc, but I think an Image() will be faster.

I'd like some input on this, since I'm quite clueless.

Actual examples:

I have a little car I want to draw on the screen. Let's say it's a racing game and I want the keyboard to move the car. Should the car be an Image() or a `<canvas>`.

I have a background landscape to put on the back of my 2D Platformer. Image() or `<canvas>`?

Comment: The speed depends on the implementation of the browser. In some browsers one could be faster, in others the other.

Comment: Also this depends on the needs.

Comment: Give us some use cases for your "scenario" and we might be able to provide some help, otherwise this is looking like too general a question to properly answer. Why is performance an issue for you? Are the image rendering times a bottleneck?

Answer (score -3):

I will suggest SVG images, they are memory efficient an you can change the color with css. Here some good articles about it:

[Using SVG for Flexible, Scalable, and Fun Backgrounds](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/using-svg-for-flexible-scalable-and-fun-backgrounds-part-ii/)

[Can I change the fill color of an svg path with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529300/can-i-change-the-fill-color-of-an-svg-path-with-css)

Comment: If he was making a vector game maybe I would agree, but hes specifically asking about canvas. It would be like me just suggesting he use Flash or Unity instead.