# How to set fill color for svg rect

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the following icon in svg, which contain a rect.
I need to color in red (now they are in white).
With my current CSS solution I am not able to get the result wanted.
Any idea how to fix it?

Notes this question is different from other because it related to rect only and not path.

```css
.icon rect {
  fill: red;
}

html {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon">
  <svg width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 16 20" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
      <g transform="translate(-28.000000, -26.000000)" stroke-width="2" stroke="#FFFFFF">
        <rect x="43" y="27" width="1" height="18"></rect>
        <rect x="29" y="27" width="1" height="18"></rect>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I change the fill color of an svg path with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529300/can-i-change-the-fill-color-of-an-svg-path-with-css)

Comment: The rect elements have no visible fill because 1/2 the stroke width is >= the width so all you see is the stroke and stroke colour.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to change `stroke` value of `g` (a value that you also specified inline) because it's going above the rect:

```css
.icon g {
  stroke: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.icon rect {
  fill: red;
}

html {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon">
  <svg width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 16 20" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
      <g transform="translate(-28.000000, -26.000000)" stroke-width="2" stroke="#FFFFFF">
        <rect x="43" y="27" width="1" height="18"></rect>
        <rect x="29" y="27" width="1" height="18"></rect>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Or simply remove stroke from g :

```css
.icon rect {
  fill: red;
}

html {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon">
  <svg width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 16 20" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
      <g transform="translate(-28.000000, -26.000000)" >
        <rect x="43" y="27" width="1" height="18"></rect>
        <rect x="29" y="27" width="1" height="18"></rect>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: why do you apply on g stroke and not on rect?

Comment: Or he could have just searched SO and found a few examples of the same thing in questions already answered.

Comment: @Radex because the stroke is coming above the rect, read more here :https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_stroking.asp

Comment: @Radex check again my answer and you will undertand more ;)