# it doesn't work when i hover my li's in my navbar

Tags: html, css, navbar

when i clone rolex website to improve myself, when i hover over the li's in my navigation bar i want the color of both my svgs and a tags to change but it's not working;

```css
#nav-bar .nav-links {
  display: flex;
}

#nav-bar .nav-links li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.nav-links li:hover {
  color: red;
  /*it doesnt work, i tried it*/
}

#nav-bar .nav-links svg {
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  fill: #fefefe;
}

#nav-bar .nav-links li a {
  color: #fefefe;
  font-size: 14.5px;
  margin-left: 8px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-links">
  <li>
    <svg height="18" width="18" viewBox="0 0 15 15" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path
                        d="m14.8 13.4-4-4c.7-1 1.1-2.1 1.1-3.4 0-3.2-2.6-5.8-5.8-5.8-3.3 0-5.9 2.6-5.9 5.8s2.6 5.8 5.8 5.8c1.3 0 2.4-.4 3.4-1.1l4 4zm-8.8-3.5c-2.1 0-3.9-1.7-3.9-3.9 0-2.1 1.8-3.9 3.9-3.9s3.9 1.8 3.9 3.9c0 2.2-1.7 3.9-3.9 3.9z">
                    </path>
                </svg>
    <a class="nav-a" href="#">Search</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 15 15">
                    <path
                        d="M7.5,0.5c-3,0-5.4,2.4-5.4,5.4c0,1.1,0.7,2.6,1.7,4c1.7,2.3,3.7,4.6,3.7,4.6s2-2.4,3.7-4.6  c0.9-1.4,1.7-2.9,1.7-4C12.9,2.9,10.5,0.5,7.5,0.5z M7.5,8.4C6.1,8.4,5,7.2,5,5.9c0-1.4,1.1-2.5,2.5-2.5S10,4.5,10,5.9  S8.9,8.4,7.5,8.4z">
                    </path>
                </svg>
    <a class="nav-a" href="#">Store locator</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <svg class="undefined css-1emgvlg e10fsun60" height="18" width="18" viewBox="0 0 15 15" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-hidden="true" alt="">
                    <path
                        d="m7.5 14.8-6.2-6.2c-1.7-1.7-1.7-4.5 0-6.2.8-.8 1.9-1.3 3.1-1.3 1.2 0 2.2.5 3.1 1.3v.1c.8-.8 1.9-1.3 3.1-1.3s2.2.5 3.1 1.3c1.7 1.7 1.7 4.5 0 6.2zm-3.1-11.6c-.6 0-1.2.2-1.6.7-.9.9-.9 2.4 0 3.3l4.7 4.8 4.7-4.8c.9-.9.9-2.4 0-3.3-.8-.9-2.4-.9-3.2 0l-1.5 1.5-1.5-1.5c-.4-.5-1-.7-1.6-.7z">
                    </path>
                </svg>
    <a class="nav-a" href="#">Favourites</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

i tried this way

```
.nav-links li:hover{
    color: red;
}
```

but not worked, please help me, why it not working

Answer (score 1):

This targets the `li` element.

> ```
> .nav-links li:hover{
>    color: red; /*it doesnt work, i tried it*/
> }
> ```

---

> want the color of both my svgs

`color` doesn't do anything on an SVG. You need to target a more specific element (like the `path`) and use a propertiy that actually affects it (like [`fill`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529300/can-i-change-the-fill-color-of-an-svg-path-with-css).

> and a tags to change but it's not working;

You gave the `a` elements their own color:

> ```
> #nav-bar .nav-links li a {
>     color: #fefefe;
> ```

Even if you didn't, `a` elements have their own colour by default.

They aren't going to `inherit` from the the `li`.

Again, you need to target the `a` element itself, not the `li`.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by **Quentin** and **iorgv**:
svg elements wont't automatically inherit the parent's `color` value but expect a `fill` property value instead.

However, you can simplify your css rules by applying a [`fill: currentColor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/color) value like so

```
svg path{
  fill: currentColor;
}
```

It's crucial to avoid specific fill styles applied to the `<svg>` or `<path>` element.

```css
.nav-links {
  display: flex;
}

.nav-links li a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-links li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  color:green;
}

/* icon specific styles */
.nav-links svg {
  display: inline-block;
  height:1em;
}

.nav-links path{
  fill: currentColor;
}

.nav-links li a {
  color:inherit;
  font-size: 14.5px;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.nav-links li:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-links">
  <li>
    <svg height="18" width="18" viewBox="0 0 15 15" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="m14.8 13.4-4-4c.7-1 1.1-2.1 1.1-3.4 0-3.2-2.6-5.8-5.8-5.8-3.3 0-5.9 2.6-5.9 5.8s2.6 5.8 5.8 5.8c1.3 0 2.4-.4 3.4-1.1l4 4zm-8.8-3.5c-2.1 0-3.9-1.7-3.9-3.9 0-2.1 1.8-3.9 3.9-3.9s3.9 1.8 3.9 3.9c0 2.2-1.7 3.9-3.9 3.9z">
      </path>
    </svg>
    <a class="nav-a" href="#">Search</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 15 15">
      <path d="M7.5,0.5c-3,0-5.4,2.4-5.4,5.4c0,1.1,0.7,2.6,1.7,4c1.7,2.3,3.7,4.6,3.7,4.6s2-2.4,3.7-4.6  c0.9-1.4,1.7-2.9,1.7-4C12.9,2.9,10.5,0.5,7.5,0.5z M7.5,8.4C6.1,8.4,5,7.2,5,5.9c0-1.4,1.1-2.5,2.5-2.5S10,4.5,10,5.9  S8.9,8.4,7.5,8.4z">
      </path>
    </svg>
    <a class="nav-a" href="#">Store locator</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <svg class="undefined css-1emgvlg e10fsun60" height="18" width="18" viewBox="0 0 15 15" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-hidden="true" alt="">
      <path d="m7.5 14.8-6.2-6.2c-1.7-1.7-1.7-4.5 0-6.2.8-.8 1.9-1.3 3.1-1.3 1.2 0 2.2.5 3.1 1.3v.1c.8-.8 1.9-1.3 3.1-1.3s2.2.5 3.1 1.3c1.7 1.7 1.7 4.5 0 6.2zm-3.1-11.6c-.6 0-1.2.2-1.6.7-.9.9-.9 2.4 0 3.3l4.7 4.8 4.7-4.8c.9-.9.9-2.4 0-3.3-.8-.9-2.4-.9-3.2 0l-1.5 1.5-1.5-1.5c-.4-.5-1-.7-1.6-.7z">
      </path>
    </svg>
    <a class="nav-a" href="#">Favourites</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Wrapping the svg icons within your `<a>` elements can also simplify the css rules.

```css
body{
  background: #ccc
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
}

.nav-links li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  color:green;
}

.nav-links li:hover {
  color: red;
}

/**
* no text decoration 
* inherit color
*/
.nav-links a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color:inherit;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

/* default svg icon size */
.nav-links
svg{
  display: inline-block;
  height:1em;
}

.nav-links path{
  fill: currentColor;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-links">
  <li>
    <a class="nav-a" href="#">
    <svg height="18" width="18" viewBox="0 0 15 15" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path d="m14.8 13.4-4-4c.7-1 1.1-2.1 1.1-3.4 0-3.2-2.6-5.8-5.8-5.8-3.3 0-5.9 2.6-5.9 5.8s2.6 5.8 5.8 5.8c1.3 0 2.4-.4 3.4-1.1l4 4zm-8.8-3.5c-2.1 0-3.9-1.7-3.9-3.9 0-2.1 1.8-3.9 3.9-3.9s3.9 1.8 3.9 3.9c0 2.2-1.7 3.9-3.9 3.9z">
      </path>
    </svg>
      Search</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="nav-a" href="#">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 15 15">
      <path d="M7.5,0.5c-3,0-5.4,2.4-5.4,5.4c0,1.1,0.7,2.6,1.7,4c1.7,2.3,3.7,4.6,3.7,4.6s2-2.4,3.7-4.6  c0.9-1.4,1.7-2.9,1.7-4C12.9,2.9,10.5,0.5,7.5,0.5z M7.5,8.4C6.1,8.4,5,7.2,5,5.9c0-1.4,1.1-2.5,2.5-2.5S10,4.5,10,5.9  S8.9,8.4,7.5,8.4z">
      </path>
    </svg>
      
      Store locator</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="nav-a" href="#"><svg class="undefined css-1emgvlg e10fsun60" height="18" width="18" viewBox="0 0 15 15" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-hidden="true" alt="">
      <path d="m7.5 14.8-6.2-6.2c-1.7-1.7-1.7-4.5 0-6.2.8-.8 1.9-1.3 3.1-1.3 1.2 0 2.2.5 3.1 1.3v.1c.8-.8 1.9-1.3 3.1-1.3s2.2.5 3.1 1.3c1.7 1.7 1.7 4.5 0 6.2zm-3.1-11.6c-.6 0-1.2.2-1.6.7-.9.9-.9 2.4 0 3.3l4.7 4.8 4.7-4.8c.9-.9.9-2.4 0-3.3-.8-.9-2.4-.9-3.2 0l-1.5 1.5-1.5-1.5c-.4-.5-1-.7-1.6-.7z">
      </path>
    </svg>
      Favourites</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice! A solution with `currentColor`, so we don't need to declare it inline. Will definitely use it in my future projects! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have to address the `a` separately, and the `fill` color must be defined for the `svg` too, and only `fill` color can be changed for the `svg`.

```css
#nav-bar .nav-links {
  display: flex;
}

#nav-bar .nav-links li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.nav-links li:hover {
  color: red;
  /*it doesnt work, i tried it*/
}

#nav-bar .nav-links svg {
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  fill: #fefefe;
}

#nav-bar .nav-links li a {
  color: #fefefe;
  font-size: 14.5px;
  margin-left: 8px;
}


/*new code from here*/

.nav-links li a:hover {
  color: red;
}
svg path {
  fill: currentColor; /* workaround by herrstrietzel */
}
.nav-links li:hover path {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-links">
  <li>
    <svg height="18" width="18" viewBox="0 0 15 15" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path 
                        d="m14.8 13.4-4-4c.7-1 1.1-2.1 1.1-3.4 0-3.2-2.6-5.8-5.8-5.8-3.3 0-5.9 2.6-5.9 5.8s2.6 5.8 5.8 5.8c1.3 0 2.4-.4 3.4-1.1l4 4zm-8.8-3.5c-2.1 0-3.9-1.7-3.9-3.9 0-2.1 1.8-3.9 3.9-3.9s3.9 1.8 3.9 3.9c0 2.2-1.7 3.9-3.9 3.9z">
                    </path>
                </svg>
    <a class="nav-a" href="#">Search</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 15 15">
                    <path 
                        d="M7.5,0.5c-3,0-5.4,2.4-5.4,5.4c0,1.1,0.7,2.6,1.7,4c1.7,2.3,3.7,4.6,3.7,4.6s2-2.4,3.7-4.6  c0.9-1.4,1.7-2.9,1.7-4C12.9,2.9,10.5,0.5,7.5,0.5z M7.5,8.4C6.1,8.4,5,7.2,5,5.9c0-1.4,1.1-2.5,2.5-2.5S10,4.5,10,5.9  S8.9,8.4,7.5,8.4z">
                    </path>
                </svg>
    <a class="nav-a" href="#">Store locator</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <svg class="undefined css-1emgvlg e10fsun60" height="18" width="18" viewBox="0 0 15 15" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-hidden="true" alt="">
                    <path 
                        d="m7.5 14.8-6.2-6.2c-1.7-1.7-1.7-4.5 0-6.2.8-.8 1.9-1.3 3.1-1.3 1.2 0 2.2.5 3.1 1.3v.1c.8-.8 1.9-1.3 3.1-1.3s2.2.5 3.1 1.3c1.7 1.7 1.7 4.5 0 6.2zm-3.1-11.6c-.6 0-1.2.2-1.6.7-.9.9-.9 2.4 0 3.3l4.7 4.8 4.7-4.8c.9-.9.9-2.4 0-3.3-.8-.9-2.4-.9-3.2 0l-1.5 1.5-1.5-1.5c-.4-.5-1-.7-1.6-.7z">
                    </path>
                </svg>
    <a class="nav-a" href="#">Favourites</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```