# Load external SVG into the DOM, current document not subdocument

Tags: jquery, html, svg

I am trying to load an external SVG document into a simple web page so that I can use it as a basic chloropeth map. However, using `<object data=""></object>` in the HTML results in the SVG loading as a subdocument.

Basically I am unable to query the SVG paths by ID using jquery (ex: `$('#NY').css("fill", "red")` doesn't do anything). Obviously I can just cut and paste the actual SVG content into the HTML, but I'm curious if there is a way to get the SVG path stuff to load into the HTML document using `<object>` or similar.

**The HTML:**

```
<object data="/static/metric/img/map_US.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
</object>
```

**Here's a shot of the DOM using the console** (notice the SVG stuff is *inside* a `#document` subdocument!):

[image: SVG Subdocument DOM]

Comment: Have you considered using [`XMLHttpRequest`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) instead? If all you want to do is load some data and then insert it to the document that's more efficient than using <object>. If you like js libraries, then there's http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Snap.load and https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests to make loading data even easier.

Comment: @ErikDahlström I'll look into this later. I'm currently using d3 for many visualization related things. The main motivation for my question was to see if there is a "native" way to load external SVG content into HTML much like `<img>` or any other tag. Strange that there is no straightforward way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is [`getSVGDocument`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#__svg__GetSVGDocument__getSVGDocument) or `contentDocument`:

```
document.getElementById('thesvg').getSVGDocument().getElementById('theelement')
```

or

```
document.getElementById('thesvg').contentDocument.getElementById('theelement')
```

You probably want to test for both, I'm not quite sure what the compatibility is with various browsers at the moment.

**Update**

You can move nodes from the SVG subdocument to the main one using `adoptNode`. With an empty `<svg>` element (called `target`) in the main document:

```
o = document.getElementById('thesvg').contentDocument.getElementById('theelement');
document.adoptNode(o);
document.getElementById('target').appendChild(o);
```

Again, not sure what the compatibility is for this, but it works in Safari. According to the [W3C DOM FAQ](http://www.w3.org/DOM/faq.html#moveNode), this is a DOM Level 3 method. Level 2 has `importNode` which apparently allows a copy rather than a move. And as suggested by the same FAQ, you can always walk through the subdocument and re-create the hierarchy in the main document using `createNode` and friends.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this seems to be a way to query the subdocuments. I am specifically looking for a way to load an SVG into the HTML via `object`, `embed`, or similar and make it part of the native DOM; i.e., *no subdocuments*.

Comment: Updated the answer with `adoptNode` and more.

Comment: It works on Firefox. What a nasty way of doing things! But hey, it works... It's much more straightforward to just have the SVG stuff directly in your HTML. Cheers.

Comment: @James I improved a bit on this for that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72804140/3795597 and made it into a one-liner: `<object type="image/svg+xml" data="illustration.svg" onload="this.parentNode.replaceChild(this.contentDocument.documentElement, this);"></object>`. Thanks for giving me the idea.