# Inline External SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I'd like to use an external SVG image for social media links that I can use the CSS fill property for. HTML looks like this:

```
<a><svg width="30" height="30">
     <use xlink:href="image/svg/instagram.svg" class="insta"></use>
</svg>Instagram</a>
```

but the SVG is not showing up. Further, my CSS looks like this:

```
.insta {
     fill: blue;
}
```

Any help on how to include inline SVG files would be really appreciated. Website is [here](http://curtisupshall.com).

Comment: Probable duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252409/manipulating-external-svg-file-style-properties-with-css?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap your SVG icon inside the svg file element inside a symbol element

```
<symbol id="item">
...
</symbol>
```

and reference that in your href for this to work.

```
<a><svg width="30" height="30">
     <use xlink:href="image/svg/instagram.svg#item" class="insta"></use>
</svg>Instagram</a>
```