# Changing SVG color using CSS

Tags: html, css, svg

I tried to change the svg picture color in my html using css and i tried using fill=currentColor in the svg doc as well but it didnt give me the expected result

I tried various tutorials and methods but it was not working for me

The below code is the svg document code.

```
   <svg width="22" height="19" viewBox="0 0 22 19" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M9.69795 0.799227C10.0605 0.488302 10.5223 0.317383 11 0.317383C11.4776 0.317383 11.9394 0.488302 12.302 0.799227L18.638 6.22923L21.125 8.21923C21.2275 8.3013 21.3129 8.40278 21.3763 8.51785C21.4396 8.63293 21.4797 8.75936 21.4941 8.88992C21.5086 9.02048 21.4973 9.15261 21.4607 9.27878C21.4241 9.40494 21.363 9.52267 21.281 9.62523C21.1989 9.72779 21.0974 9.81318 20.9823 9.87653C20.8672 9.93987 20.7408 9.97993 20.6103 9.99442C20.4797 10.0089 20.3476 9.99753 20.2214 9.96095C20.0952 9.92438 19.9775 9.8633 19.875 9.78123L19 9.08123V17.0002C19 17.5307 18.7892 18.0394 18.4142 18.4144C18.0391 18.7895 17.5304 19.0002 17 19.0002H13V14.0002C13 13.4698 12.7892 12.9611 12.4142 12.586C12.0391 12.2109 11.5304 12.0002 11 12.0002C10.4695 12.0002 9.96081 12.2109 9.58574 12.586C9.21067 12.9611 8.99995 13.4698 8.99995 14.0002V19.0002H4.99995C4.46952 19.0002 3.96081 18.7895 3.58574 18.4144C3.21067 18.0394 2.99995 17.5307 2.99995 17.0002V9.08023L2.12495 9.78023C2.02309 9.86721 1.90478 9.93284 1.77707 9.97322C1.64935 10.0136 1.51482 10.0279 1.38146 10.0153C1.24811 10.0027 1.11865 9.96344 1.00076 9.89983C0.882872 9.83623 0.778965 9.74959 0.695205 9.64506C0.611446 9.54053 0.549541 9.42023 0.513165 9.29132C0.476789 9.1624 0.466684 9.02749 0.48345 8.89459C0.500215 8.76169 0.543509 8.63352 0.610762 8.51768C0.678016 8.40183 0.767857 8.30068 0.874953 8.22023L3.36195 6.23023L9.69795 0.799227Z" fill="currentColor"/>
</svg>
```

And in the html i used it like this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar-link">
      <div class="in">
        <a style="color: yellow;" href="#"><img src="./../assets/Home.svg"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="in">
        <a class="a" href="#">Dashboard</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The assets folder has the Home.svg and i just used it here and possible css solutions so that i can get this working?

EDIT : I used color in anchor tag and gave it yellow so it this code correct or is there something else to do get my expected result. So in the document i put fill=currentColor at the end but the color doesnt change as i want. But if i specify yellow instead of currentColor it works fine. Any way i can change the color using css?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [img src SVG changing the styles with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933430/img-src-svg-changing-the-styles-with-css) and [How can I change the color of an 'svg' element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252472/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-an-svg-element)

Comment: Take inspiration from [the ``<load-file>`` Web Component](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `fill="#BCBCBC"` from `<path>`, now css works!

```css
svg {
  fill: rgb(77, 10, 235);
}
```

```html
    <svg width="22" height="19" viewBox="0 0 22 19" fill="red" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path
        fill-rule="evenodd"
        clip-rule="evenodd"
        d="M9.69795 0.799227C10.0605 0.488302 10.5223 0.317383 11 0.317383C11.4776 0.317383 11.9394 0.488302 12.302 0.799227L18.638 6.22923L21.125 8.21923C21.2275 8.3013 21.3129 8.40278 21.3763 8.51785C21.4396 8.63293 21.4797 8.75936 21.4941 8.88992C21.5086 9.02048 21.4973 9.15261 21.4607 9.27878C21.4241 9.40494 21.363 9.52267 21.281 9.62523C21.1989 9.72779 21.0974 9.81318 20.9823 9.87653C20.8672 9.93987 20.7408 9.97993 20.6103 9.99442C20.4797 10.0089 20.3476 9.99753 20.2214 9.96095C20.0952 9.92438 19.9775 9.8633 19.875 9.78123L19 9.08123V17.0002C19 17.5307 18.7892 18.0394 18.4142 18.4144C18.0391 18.7895 17.5304 19.0002 17 19.0002H13V14.0002C13 13.4698 12.7892 12.9611 12.4142 12.586C12.0391 12.2109 11.5304 12.0002 11 12.0002C10.4695 12.0002 9.96081 12.2109 9.58574 12.586C9.21067 12.9611 8.99995 13.4698 8.99995 14.0002V19.0002H4.99995C4.46952 19.0002 3.96081 18.7895 3.58574 18.4144C3.21067 18.0394 2.99995 17.5307 2.99995 17.0002V9.08023L2.12495 9.78023C2.02309 9.86721 1.90478 9.93284 1.77707 9.97322C1.64935 10.0136 1.51482 10.0279 1.38146 10.0153C1.24811 10.0027 1.11865 9.96344 1.00076 9.89983C0.882872 9.83623 0.778965 9.74959 0.695205 9.64506C0.611446 9.54053 0.549541 9.42023 0.513165 9.29132C0.476789 9.1624 0.466684 9.02749 0.48345 8.89459C0.500215 8.76169 0.543509 8.63352 0.610762 8.51768C0.678016 8.40183 0.767857 8.30068 0.874953 8.22023L3.36195 6.23023L9.69795 0.799227Z" />
    </svg>
```

Comment: I tried this method but i dont get the color. Maybe because im using an image tag as stated above with the html code.

Comment: So I swapped out image tag with the svg code and did the fill: red; And it works. Though i wanted it clean with the resources being in the assets folder and linked through img tag. Still its great that i could resolve it like that atleast. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 3):

You have a `fill="#BCBCBC"` on your path (at the very end) which is overwriting the `fill="currentColor"` on the svg.

Comment: ah yah i had that i removed it and tried again but it didnt work

Comment: Ah, didn't see your edit. You can't style external SVGs, you can only style them if they're inline. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252409/manipulating-external-svg-file-style-properties-with-css

Comment: Actually Yah i read something on how it was not possible to do so but then i came across few examples that did it. But it used xlink:href and <use> tag. I dont know much about svg so i dont have any idea on what that is. I tried including the svg in image tag and that gave me my current problem. I camee accross another video on how it is done but it had scss so it didnt fit to be my solution. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FEy5zPdbN9c&t=185s&ab_channel=FrontDev